# Flutter package/method to view files in-app

Tags: flutter, dart, pdf

For the app I am currently developing I want to have a page in which the user can open and read een select set of documents. Mainly PDFs but Excel and Word files should also work. I want it to happen in-app, so the user is not sent to a website.

Is there any Widget I can use or a package? I've looked around but most of what I find is just for opening a file to use the contents, not to have the user view it. If there is not, how would I go about implementing this myself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found and used the 'flutter_webview' package to solve my problem. It can show webpages, but also display all the files I need in-app.